# get value from table A only if a specific value not present in table B

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have data in Table A but I need to fetch this data only if the table B doesn't contain the value withdrawn for that primary key which is ID.

I have tried Left Join on Table A and Table B and tried to filter the results with Table B status not having withdrawn condition.

```
SELECT * from
from TableA
Left join TableB ON TableB.dealid  = TableA.DealID
where TableA.Status in ('Files Returned', 'Files Sent')
AND TableA.Type in ('Refinance', 'Purchase')
AND TableB.Status <> 'Withdrawn'
```

I am still getting a row from table A which I am not supposed to.

```
Table A

FileID      Type        Amount      Status
4           Refinance   100190.00   Files Returned


Table B

Status                      FileID
Files Returned                4
Files Sent                    4
Instructions Received         4
Withdrawn                     4
```

Comment: Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edit the answer. Hope this works for your needs.

```
;
    WITH    cte
              AS ( SELECT   [a].[fileid] ,
                            [a].[type] ,
                            [a].[amount] ,
                            [a].[status] ,
                            [b].[status] AS 'statusB'
                   FROM     TableA AS a
                   INNER JOIN TableB AS b ON b.[FileId] = a.[fileid]
                   WHERE    a.status IN ( 'Files Returned', 'Files Sent' )
                            AND a.type IN ( 'Refinance', 'Purchase' )
                 )
        SELECT  [c].[fileid] ,
                [c].[type] ,
                [c].[amount] ,
                [c].[status]
        FROM    [cte] AS c
        WHERE   [c].[fileid] NOT IN ( SELECT DISTINCT
                                                [fileid]
                                      FROM      [cte]
                                      WHERE     [statusB] = 'Withdrawn' );
```

Comment: my requirement is When Withdrawn is there in table B, I dont want to get a match in Table A for fileid 4

Comment: Which column is primary key? 'FileId' or 'DealID'?

Comment: FileId is the foreign key in table B.